# Android Flashlight app

Tags: java, beginner, android

This is my first project, a Flashlight application for Android-based devices:

```
public class main extends Activity
{
    private static final byte MENU_EXIT = 0, MENU_ABOUT = 1;
    private static boolean FlashlightState;
    private static long BackPressed;
    private static ImageView Lamp;
    private Flashlight FLASHLIGHT = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        FlashlightState = false;
        Lamp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVw_Lamp);
        FLASHLIGHT = new Flashlight(this.getApplicationContext());

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight) FLASHLIGHT.Open();

        Lamp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Lamp.setEnabled(false);

                if (getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) != null)
                {
                    AudioManager VibratorState = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    if (VibratorState.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
                    {
                        Vibrator Switch = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        Switch.vibrate(50);
                    }
                    VibratorState = null;
                }

                if (!FlashlightState) turnOnFlashlight();
                else turnOffFlashlight();

                Lamp.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }
        });

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        BackPressed = 0;

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight) FLASHLIGHT.Open();

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        this.turnOffFlashlight();
        BackPressed = 0;

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight) FLASHLIGHT.Close();

        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if ((BackPressed + 2000) > System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            finish();
            this.onDestroy();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Exit_Message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_EXIT, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.Exit)).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ABOUT, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.About)).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case MENU_EXIT:
                finish();
                this.onDestroy();
            break;
            case MENU_ABOUT:
                this.showAboutBox();
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private final void showAboutBox()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder AboutBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AboutBox.setTitle(getString(R.string.About));
        AboutBox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        AboutBox.setMessage("Name:\nVisionlight\n\nDescription:\nFlashlight application for Android based devices.\n\nVersion:\n1.0.0\n\nLanguages:\nEnglish/International, Persian, Arabic\n\nPlatform:\nAndroid +2.2.x(Froyo)\n\nPermissions:\nCamera, Flashlight, Vibrate, Wake Lock.\n\nUses-feature:\nCamera [NR], Flashlight [NR].\n\nProducer/Developer:\nYousha Aleayoub(Y.P.Y)\n\nLicense:\nBSD\n\nContact:\nYousha.A@Hotmail.com\n\nLink:\nhttp://yousha.blog.ir/");

        AboutBox.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AboutBox.create().show();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.turnOffFlashlight();

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight) FLASHLIGHT.Close();

        FLASHLIGHT = null;
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        return;
    }

    private final void turnOnFlashlight()
    {
        FlashlightState = true;
        Lamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight)
        {
            FLASHLIGHT.On();
        }
        else
        {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams Layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
            Layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
            getWindow().setAttributes(Layout);
            findViewById(R.id.lnrLyt_Main).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        return;
    }

    private final void turnOffFlashlight()
    {
        FlashlightState = false;
        Lamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);

        if (Flashlight.hasFlashlight) FLASHLIGHT.Off();
        else findViewById(R.id.lnrLyt_Main).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        return;
    }
}
```

What do you think? Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Use camelcase for your variable names.

Instead of:
`public boolean MyBoolean` write `public boolean myBoolean`

(This is to increase readability so you can tell the difference between class and object more clearly)

### Use braces for if else statements

In your code you use:

```
        if (!FlashlightState) turnOnFlashlight();
        else turnOffFlashlight();
```

More appropriate would be to use:

```
if(!FlashlightState) {
  turnOnFlashlight();
} else {
  turnOffFlashlight();
}
```

If you absolutely want to omit braces, omit them for single-statement solely-if clauses only. Such as:

`if(bool) doSomething(); //No else statements`

### Using killProcess is a bad habit. (Destroy all your activities instead)

If you want to quit an App, just make sure all activities in the app are `finish();`'ed.
If you want to quit an activity, use `finish();`, this will call `onDestroy()` on your activity. You should let the OS handle the lifecycle of your activities as much as possible. Assuming that you have a single activity app, calling `finish();` should destroy the only activity in your app, thus quitting it at the first opportunity.

### Redundant return statements at the end of void functions.

Most of your functions have the statement `return;` in them at the end. This is completely redundant and serves no use.

### Redundant final keyword in private method declarations

Your private methods are not going to be overridden or anything, they don't need the final keyword.

`private`: *This method cannot be overridden by a subclass*

`final`: *This method cannot be overridden by a subclass*

`private final`: *This method cannot be overridden by a subclass and this method cannot be overridden by a subclass* (**Redundant**)

---

*Optional*:

#### Refactor away your turnOn and turnOff functions.

You currently call two different functions that do a roughly similar thing depending on whether you toggle the flashlight on or off.

Instead of the following:

```
        if (!FlashlightState) turnOnFlashlight();
        else turnOffFlashlight();
```

You could do something like:

```
toggleFlashLight();
```

In toggle flashlight you could do:

```
private void toggleFlashLight() {

  FlashlightState = !FlashlightState;

  if(FlashlightState) {
    //Turn it on;
  } else {
    //Turn it off;
  }
}
```

There's a dozen other ways to design it. (Where do you want to do the actual toggling of your boolean, etc. But this is just one example)

Answer (score 11):

This is on top of what [@ZeroStatic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51647/zerostatic) already said.

---

These mutable static variables are deeply troubling:

> ```
> private static boolean FlashlightState;
> private static long BackPressed;
> private static ImageView Lamp;
> ```

Why are these static? Do you intend to run multiple instances of this activity at the same time? What for? I suggest to make all of these non-static.

---

What is this about:

> ```
> AudioManager VibratorState = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
> // ...
> VibratorState = null;
> ```

First of all, you call an audio service `VibratorState`, which is completely misleading, and then why do you set it to `null`? Is there a documentation somewhere that recommends this practice? If not, it's reasonable to assume that the variable will be garbage collected normally.

---

This is pointless:

> ```
> finish();
> this.onDestroy();
> ```

It's enough to call `finish()`, the framework will call `onDestroy`.

---

It's not recommended to include texts like this inside the Java code of Android apps:

> ```
>     AboutBox.setMessage("Name:\nVisionlight\n\nDescription:\nFlashlight application for Android based devices.\n\nVersion:\n1.0.0\n\nPlatform:\nAndroid +2.2.x(Froyo)\n\nPermissions:\nCamera, Flashlight, Vibrate, Wake Lock.\n\nUses-feature:\nCamera [NR], Flashlight [NR].\n\nProducer/Developer:\nYousha Aleayoub(Y.P.Y)\n\nLicense:\nBSD\n\nContact:\nYousha.A@Hotmail.com\n\nLink:\nhttp://yousha.blog.ir/");
> ```

This belongs to `strings.xml`.

Also, in general, don't put such extremely long lines in code. As much as possible, it's to keep lines short enough to fit within a window. You could easily break this into 4 and it would have been easier to read without having to scroll so much to the right.

---

Use `CamelCase` for class names. But `main` has an even bigger problem that it doesn't tell anything about the class. The common convention is to name activities as `SomethingActivity`, so in your case `FlashlightActivity` is an obvious choice.

---

Use all capital letters for static constants only, so instead of:

> ```
> private Flashlight FLASHLIGHT = null;
> ```

Should be:

```
private Flashlight flashlight = null;
```

Comment: Why make them non static